# dotnet web application runs in docker container but is not active

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I've tried editing the dockerfile, i get a successful build and running the container but the container doesn't reflect when i do "docker ps". i get this error when i check the container logs "Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:

- You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
- You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-QuintAPI.dll does not exist.
- You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
  "

Comment: Can you include the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the executable file specified in the docker file was wrongly spelled. Once that was corrected, everything worked perfect.